# How to perform URL redirects properly?

Tags: url, redirect, symfony1

In the action class, I have this one at the end of the function:

```
$this->redirect("/myproject_dev.php/login/");
```

In which I hard code the development project name in the url.  of course it works while I'm doing development but when it comes to production, I need to remove that.

so, how do I find out the project name ("myproject_dev.php") in the code?  so that I can do this:

```
$this->redirect($myProjectDevName . "login/");
```

or.. is there a smart way to handle this?

thanks.

------  ADDition ---

so, I used the public_path as suggested. but it only returns the root path.

I'm wondering if there is a function that when I run in development mode:

```
http://mydomain.com/myproject_dev.php/whatever
```

in its action class:
    $this->redirect(public_path('login'));
and result in
    http://mydomain.com/myproject_dev.php/login

while if I run in production:
    http://mydomain.com/whatever
the action class is unchanged:
    $this->redirect(public_path('login'));
it will return this:
    http://mydomain.com/login

or.. how to get the application name and symfony environment name?

:)

Comment: What's the context of your redirection - specifically, why do you need to specify the app you're redirecting to?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the symfony routing system and call a routing rule from your routing.yml:

```
$this->redirect('@login');
```

This way it becomes separate of your environment and you wan't need to change anything when you're ready to move to production.

Comment: i tried. but @login doesn't work. what should I set in the routing rule?

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
 public_path()
```

http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/UrlHelper#method_public_path

Comment: It shows the public_path when it is in production.  however, in development, it wont' return "/myproject_dev.php/login/" if I pass in public_path("login/");

Answer (score 0):

try this put this in your function

```
$this->redirect("MODULENAME/ACTION");

ex: $this->redirect("pim/admin");
```

this will redirect you to the pim module admin action...